# Can an Ansible control machine be a Linux VM?

Tags: windows, ansible

I am researching Ansible and am figuring out what is required to use it in a Windows only environment. I came across this link:

http://docs.ansible.com/intro_windows.html

and there it says that I need a Linux control machine.

I don't want to make it a requirement for customers who are Windows shops to setup and manage a Linux machine. So can I run a Linux VM on a Windows machine and use that as my control machine? I haven't tried this yet but wanted to know if there are any gotchas with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use a Linux VM to execute your Ansible playbooks. We did this for a coworker who ran Windows-only and it works fine as long as you configure the VM to be able to SSH into the Ansible-managed servers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it can be a VM but the best thing is to use `virtualenv` and install `ansible` inside the virtualenv, which is also true on Windows machine, I think as I am not Windows user. The main banefit is that you don't need to run the VM and give it the more resources. Hope that will help you. Thanks